# Error ParameterBindingException was unhandled in PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, citrix

I am trying to execute the Powershell command:

`Stop-BrokerSession 2904`

That number, 2904, definitely shows up in the results as seen in the code below. I used MessageBox.Show to verify the right number for the session id. However, for some reason I get this binding error. I can type that command in at the powershell prompt and it works fine, but when trying to execute it here I get this binding exception. What's the deal?

[image]

My guess as to what is wrong is that this parameter doesn't have a name. It's just a number. You put the command and the session id next to it but there isn't a name for it, it's not like "Stop-BrokerSession -SessionId 2904" it's just "Stop-BrokerSession 2904" and that I think is the issue.

Also this doesn't work:

```
logoff.parameters.Add(null, x.Properties["Uid"].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Why mark this down??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
x.Properties["Uid"].Value
```

without ToString()? As I see the value must be of Int64 type.

Comment: Yes I tried that, it won't take an int value it must be a string.